# prevent preloading of images?

Tags: css, image, preload

The website I'm working on has a list `ul` with above a 100 (`li`) bullet points. Each of them links to another html-site.
I would like to show an image preview, whenever you hover over one of the links. The image should slowly slide in from the left.

As each preview image is up to 40kb in size, I actually **don't** want to preload the images.
What would be the best way to prevent it?
I would like to do this only via CSS, without JS, if possible.

My ideas:

a) default-state: `<img>`-tag with `display:none;` hover-state: set it to `display:inline` . Problem: `transition` does not work with `display` :(.

b) simply use a `div` instead and write a CSS-rule for every `li`, so that on hover the corresponding background-image with the preview-image is assigned to it. 
Does this prevent the preloading of the image?

Comment: Nope, you need JS to do this. CSS images are loaded, regardless of "display".

Comment: If your CSS knows about the path to an image, the browser might decide to go ahead and preload it. Showing the background image on hover only seems like it would prevent preloading, but only for the first time it's loaded; after that most browsers will cache it. Keep in mind that `li:hover` won't work in IE6, so hopefully you're not trying to include it as a target browser.

Comment: Only the latest IE, Firefox and Chrome versions are targeted.

Answer (score 2):

If you add it as a background image, but only show it on hover the image won't load until the user hovers over whatever has the style. You should be able to set the background image inline instead of outputting the image file as an IMG

Comment: Thank you for the affirmation! I wasn't quite sure about that. Preloading like 4MB of images seemed like a waste to me, when most likely only 5% will be used regularly.

Comment: You have to add the style only for hover, which would make the markup a little messy, but it is doable. You can test it pretty easily by setting a large image as a background on something on hover and then waiting for it to load when you hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with just CSS because your browser will load all contents (regardless of display:none). I would recomend javascript or server side like php.

Maby jquery load could be something?
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Woudn't Matthew Darnell's solution prevent this or would it still be loaded regardless?

Comment: Anyone that remembers the time before they learned how to use image sprites for rollovers and got their first bug about the image flicker would disagree with you.

Comment: BlueHorizon: I cant say im 100% certain about background-images but i'm pretty sure it will load anyways. I'ts prob. browser dependant too. Matthew: so you mean that when you're using image sprites the browser doesn't load the whole image? Thats not true.